# Compare two different NiFis in different environments

Tags: apache-nifi

I want to compare two different environments (Prod, Dev). We have around 5-deep layers.
NiFi Home --> First --> Second ...
Which would be the approach to see the differences, besides going from layer to layer?

Comment: @BryanBende Answer is the way to go, comparing flow.xml can be a very error prone process.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of anything that can do what you are asking. The closest thing would be using NiFi Registry and having versioned flows that you start in dev, save to registry and import to prod, then you could see any changes made local to either instance per process group.

Comment: Exactly. This is before our Registry implementation. We have 100 Groups and 800 Processors. We want to see the difference between PROD and DEV, before implement in other ENVs.

Answer (score 0):

Agree with @Bryuan, if you dont use schema registry you can compare the flow.xml with traditional compare software. each processor get a unique UUID that you can use to compare content.

Comment: Yes. I saw the file and I was mentioned, we have 800 processors and the file is not good for understanding.

Comment: thats probably not a good solution for 800 processors !